# How to add texture to object in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to add to texture to my central sphere  (the earth) but when I try the object disappears. Can I have some guide to where I am going wrong. Thanks
Here is the link to my jsbin http://jsbin.com/cabape/edit?html,output . I am going to get the moon to rotate around the earth

//earth
   var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            loader.load( 'http://simpletruthsforhealthyliving.com/js/earth.jpg', function ( texture ) {

```
  var center =  new THREE.SphereGeometry(20,20,20);
var materialShereCenter = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0xee0011, color:0xff0000, specular: 0xee0000, shininess: 70,wireframe: false, map: texture } );  
centralSphere = new THREE.Mesh(center, materialShereCenter);
centralSphere.position.z        = 0;
centralSphere.position.x        = 0;
centralSphere.position.y        = 0;

scene.add(centralSphere);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needed to be added as well

var texture = new THREE.Texture();
        var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();

```
    loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
            Texture1.image = event.content;
            Texture1.needsUpdate = true;
    } );

    loader.load( 'http://simpletruthsforhealthyliving.com/js/earth.jpg' );
```